# why can i not convert this stream from process.stdout to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

So i created this server:

```
    const { createServer} = require('http');
createServer(
    (request, response) => {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });

        request.on("data", chunk => {
            response.write(chunk.toString());
        });
        request.on("end", () => {
            response.end();
        });
    }
).listen(8000);
```

as well as this client:

```
    const {request} = require('http');
request({
    hostname:'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    method:'POST',

},response=>{
    response.on("data", chunk => process.stdout(chunk.toString()));

}).end("Hello Server");
```

Initially i had `getaddrinfo ENOENT` error but when it stopped when i got on wifi, now im getting this error:

```
 response.on("data", chunk => process.stdout(chunk.toString()));
                                         ^

TypeError: process.stdout is not a function`
```

any help folks

Comment: this is gonna sound annoying, but `process.stdout` is, in fact, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

please try this one

```
var readline = require('readline');
readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
process.stdout.write(`waiting ... ${p}%`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.stdout` is a [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream). To write to a specific stream, you should use its [`write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) method (as long as it is a writeable stream). The stream object itself is not a function and can, hence, not be called like one.

```
response.on( 'data', chunk => process.stdout.write( chunk.toString() ) );
```

If your really want to pass on all content (as your current example suggests), you can also use the [`pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) method to copy all output of a (readable) stream to a (writeable) stream:

```
response.pipe( process.stdout );
```